# What is the difference between /* and / and the very end of a path on .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

On some .gitignore files we may see:

```
somedirectory/*
```

or

```
somedirectory/
```

Does this means the first will match recursively while the second one, only that directory ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The later matches the directory, but ignoring directory means ignoring all its contents. So it is recursive.

For the former, the * will only match immediate entries. But since it will match directories as well, and ignoring a directory means ignoring all its contents, it's also recursive.

Git does not track directories; a directory whose all content is ignored is as good as ignored.

Therefore there is no practical difference.

Comment: This answer is partially incorrect. Look into the my answer for details.

Answer (score 4):

They both will match recursively. But you shouldn't use `somedirectory/*` pattern because it won't match the `somedirectory/` itself. So if you have a cache folder `cache/` and ignore pattern `cache/*`, then `git clean -fd` will remove `cache/` directory with all files in it.

Be careful with patterns for IDEs :) Ignore pattern `.idea/*` can lead to clear all the settings of the project.

Comment: I don't think it matters to clean. Clean `-d` deletes any directory from which it just deleted all entries. I don't think it looks at ignores.

Comment: You can try this yourself. `git clean` respects ignore patterns and tries to keep that files untouched (without -x option).